# The router (that my PC is connected to) is continuously attempting to connect through TCP80. What would be the reasons?

Tags: http, firewalls, router, tcp

I have no access to the router nor do I have any administrative access to this local network. But every 5 minutes the router attempts to connect to my PC through port 80/tcp, and it attempts exactly 4 times each time (and tries again 5 minutes later).

I found this out from my firewall log, blocked incoming connections from 192.168.0.1 (the router). What are possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 1):

Home routers often provide an administrative GUI showing, among other things, an overview of devices connected to the local network.
Some of them will probe those devices for common services in order to offer links to those services in that overview.